# How to create a legend for overlapping alpha layers?

Tags: python, matplotlib

With matplotlib in python I'm making a plot visualizing quantiles in time series. But I'm having problems to create a legend that represents the percentiles.

This is my chart, the legend doesn't describe the data adequately.
[image: chart]

Desired legend:
[image: desired legend]

I created the graph with `plt.fill_between`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plot seems to be created by superimposing transparent layers. The color you see in the darkest layer is in reality the color of 10 combined layers.

To combine alpha layers, the following formula holds: `alpha = alpha + alpha0 * (1 - alpha)`, as explained for example in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing).

So, one could step through the legend handles and set their alpha appropriately.

Here is some example code. If you have extra handles, e.g. for the "mediana" curve, be careful to skip it in the loop.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 30, 100)
y = np.zeros_like(x)
for i in range(1, 10):
    y += 10 + np.abs(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, y.size).cumsum())
    plt.fill_between(x, y, color='b', alpha=0.1, label=f'Pct{i * 10}')
plt.plot(x, y / 2, 'b-', label='mediana')
leg = plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1.05))
alpha0 = 0.1
alpha = alpha0
for h in leg.legendHandles[:0:-1]:
    h.set_alpha(alpha)
    alpha = alpha + alpha0 * (1 - alpha)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]