# How to draw a plot like this in Python? [Screenshot included]

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

## Question

- The plot shown below seems to be created using Python, because the title and the legend looks like matplotlib.
- This plot is from this [stackexchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/386099/203358)
- How can you make the color darker, if more and more squares are overlapped?

[image]

Comment: This is how [alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) works. When a red rectangle with e.g. 0.20 alpha is drawn, it takes 80% of the background and 20% red. Drawing more such rectangles will make the area closer and closer to full red.

Comment: See also [How to create a legend for overlapping alpha layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62032865/12046409) with a formula to calculate the exact color for a given number of overlapping areas.